# window resize if method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

**EDITED**
My structure:

```
   $(window).on('resize', function () {
            if ($(".test").css("right") == "-15%" ){
            alert("hello");
        }
    });
```

But not working. when I checked console, not error found.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Looks like the `!important` part isn't retrieved by `.css('right')`: http://jsfiddle.net/GNQxX/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `!important` flag is not retrieved by the `.css()` function as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/FL6pe/

You should use this instead:

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    var defaultCSS = $('.test').css("right");
    if (defaultCSS == "-15px" ) {
        alert("hello");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Edited my post. Can you check again, please?

Comment: @user3629110 it seems that `.css()` returns the pixels rather than a percentage. See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fy2E3/

Answer (score -1):

first log the value you get and then check what youre dooing wrong

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    var defaultCSS = $('.test').css("right");
    console.log(defaultCSS);
    // take a look at what you get 
    if (defaultCSS == "to be filled" ) {
        alert("hello");
    }
});
```

you definetly do sth wrong because the if would evaluate to true if you were doing right

Comment: insofar its the right answer because with that he can see that theres no "!important" returned

Comment: Thank you. Edited my post. Can you check again, please?

Comment: @user3629110 did you really want to check "-15%" or did yu mean "-15px"